# Using QGIS to draw a line tangential to an existing circle and parallel to existing lines

Tags: qgis, line, expression, circle, geometry-generator

I am trying to draw a line tangential to a circle and parallel to an existing line. I have drawn the rough shape below showing the lines I need to draw as dashed lines.

Using the advanced digitalisation tool I can draw line A parallel to line X and line B parrallel to line Y but I cannot get either tangential to the circle.

I currently have the shape drawn as a polygon however I can draw it as individual lines to create the shape as needed and then trace the lines to create a polgon of the final shape.

I am using QGIS 3.12.1

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the line X find the nearest point on the circle - see here how to do that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381288/88814

Than you can use snapping to this point when drawing line A parallel to X.

This was the short answer. But let's get a little bit more to the details, as geometry generator and QGIS expressions are a very powerful tool to create new geometries that fulfill such conditions. You can either just create a new symbol layer (for visualization purpose only) or create actual geometries using the `Geometry by expression` tool. In both cases, the expression remains the same - that gives you a lot of flexibility to first try your expression as symbol layer for the immediate visual control. When you're finished, you can convert it to a new geometry layer.

Thus, let's get to the details: suggest we have a polygon layer `circle` and a lines layer `line`. On the circle layer, create the point nearest to the line with this expression:

```
closest_point (
        $geometry ,geometry ( 
            get_feature_by_id (
                'line', 
                array_to_string ( 
                    overlay_nearest ( 
                        'line',  "id" )
                    )
            )
        ) 
    )
```

Use this expression in the function `geometry by expression` from `menu Processing / Toolbox`, setting the circle layer as input and select point as output geometry type. This will create a new point layer, called `Nearest_point` here.

We can now continue manually (option 1) or go on with accomplishing the whole task using expressions/geometry generator (option 2, below).

**Option 1:**

Now you can copy/paste the line you want to shift (line X in your screenshot) to get line A that you want to place in parallel and as a tangent to the circle. Shift line A in parallel with `Move feature` from the toolbar. Before that, be sure to have activated snapping. Snapping should be active only for the points layer `Nearest_point` we created before, thus using the `Edit advanced configuration` of the snapping tool (not to snap on one of the vertices of the circle, in case your circle is defined by vertices).

For line Y, I would first copy/paste it to get line B, shift it in parallel near the circle where it should be eventually and than repeat the procedure - instead of "id", set the value of the id field in your lines layer of the line feature you want to find the nearest point on the circle.

[image: QGIS expression editor: create parallel tangent with snapping on closest point]

**Option 2:**
You can even automatically generate a parallel line touching the circle at one point by creating a geometry with the geometry generator. The idea is: 1) to create the nearest point to the line on the circle (what we did above), resulting `Point 1`, 2) generating another point by projecting (shifting) `Point 1` with an arbitrary distance and an azimuth (angle) that we take from the original line, thus creating `Point 2` 3) make a line from Point 1 to point 2 - because we used the azimuth (`main_angle` expression) of the line, the created line runs parallel to the original line 4) extent the line at the beginning, so that it runs out from `Point 1` in both directions. Where there is `1` in the expression, it is the id of the original line that you want to shift, change this accordingly.

Additional to that, I used the expression with_variable to define Point 1 as a variable becaus we need to insert it twice in the expression. So the final result looks like this - you can use this expression in the geometry generator or generate an actual line with `geometry by expression`. The length of the line can be adapted by changing the numer 100000 from the expression (or use a layer defined variable):

```
extend ( 
    with_variable (
        'clspnt' , 
        closest_point (
            $geometry ,
            geometry ( 
                get_feature_by_id (
                    'line', 
                    array_to_string ( 
                        overlay_nearest ( 
                            'line',  
                            1 
                        )
                    )
               )
            ) 
        ),
        make_line ( 
            @clspnt, 
            project (
                @clspnt,  
                100000,  
                radians (
                    main_angle ( 
                        geometry (
                            get_feature_by_id (
                                'line', 
                                1
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ), 
    100000 ,
    0
)
```

Here how the result looks in the geometry generator:

[image: QGIS expression editor: create parallel tangent on closes point automatically with geometry generator]

You can just change the id from 1 to 2 to get the parallel tangent of the second line:

[image: QGIS expression editor: create parallel tangent on closes point automatically with geometry generator - switch line]

Comment: Thank you for your answer I didn't manage to get the closest_point expression to work, however following the idea of using the Geometry by expression toolbox, I created lines to provide construction points (shortest_line expression) and then used the advanced digitilaisation toolbox to create the shape I needed.

Comment: If the closest_point expression did not work, you maybe should change the names of the layer ('line', in my example) or the field name ( "id" in the example above) to the names of your layer/field name. But as you're already done, there's no need to do so.