# QGIS 3.16.11 shortest distance between point and line via field calculator and overlay_nearest

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, line, distance, expression

I was searching for the shortest distance between a point (point layer with about 22000 points) and the nearest point of a line from another layer (MultiLineString). I tried Distance Matrix, nearest neighbour, distance to nearest hub. None with the expected result. But then I found something interesting on GIS SE, but only displaying the shortest line.  ([Find nearest line feature from point in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381056/find-nearest-line-feature-from-point-in-qgis/381288#381288) by @babel) It goes:

```
make_line( 
    $geometry ,
        closest_point( 
            geometry(   get_feature_by_id ('bayern_25832gis_osm_waterways_free_1',
    array_to_string( overlay_nearest ( 'bayern_25832gis_osm_waterways_free_1', "osm_id" ) 
  )
   )
   ),
    $geometry ) )
```

It looked perfect, so I tried copying it in the field calculator by exchanging `make_line` by 'distance' and voila.

Could it be thus simple?

I am just a biologist and have really no clue about expressions, their functions and so on.

How can I verify my results?

By now I only looked at the data, labeled the distances and measured by hand but cannot do this for 22.000 features.

[image: Shortest distance in meters (converted to int)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the length of the line, you **must not** replace `make_line` by `distance`, but add the function `length` to the rest of the expression, then use it in field calculator to calculate the length of the shortest line from between each point and the nearest point on a line.

Thus the whole expression will look something like what follows, where you have to replace the `[...]` part with the settings that work for you (your initial expression):

```
length ( make_line ( [...] ) )
```

Don't forget to add another closing bracket `)` at the end when adding the `length` function.

*Screenshot: the dotted lines are created with the same expression as the one you see here, just without the `length()` part. Be sure to apply this on the points layer and make the right settings: get thecorrect name of the line layer, set `Output field type` to a numerical format (`integer` or `decimal`) and check if the preview at the bottom shows the correct result:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't get it. When I put this expression into the field calculator, I get NULL for each feature. When I put it into Geometry Generator, I don't see any effect. I need the values of the shortest distance between each point and the nearest point along a line for further statistics. I do not need to display it. Therefore I tried field calculator. I also tried MMQGIS Plugin to calculate the nearest hub. The result again is not what I expected.

Comment: Take the expression that works for you to create the lines in your screenshot. Then enclose this exprssion in a `length ( )` statement: so inside these brackets, insert your whole expression. Let's say your expression to create the lines looks like this (shortened): `make_line ( [...] ) ` - then use this to calculate the length: `length (  make_line ( [...] )  )` - you see: your initial expression is inside the brackets of `length()` This does not output a line, but a value for the length. If it doesn't work, please add a screenshot showing your settings and add the exact expression you use.

Comment: I tried the length (make_line (...) expression twice, once in geometry generator, with exactly no effect, eccept that the arrows disappeared, and once in the field calculator, where I got NULL for every feature. The exact expression is: length( make_line ( 
  $geometry,
  closest_point (
      geometry (
       get_feature_by_id (
       'bayern_25832gis_osm_waterways_free_1',
    array_to_string (
         overlay_nearest (
         'bayern_25832gis_osm_waterways_free_1', "fid" )
                  )
          )
      ) , 
   $geometry )
)
 )

Comment: When I put this expression as value for labelling, I can see the values. But I cannot make statistics with them, because they are nowhere in my attribut table. When I take the field calculator and use distance instead of length (without make line), I got all the values in an extra field for further statistics and it seems to be the same values as with the length expression in the labelling field. How could this be?

Comment: Ok, probaböy you set the wrong field type in field calculator? Set ut to decimals. What does the preview in the expression editor show?

Comment: Added a screenshot: check if everything is as in your settings. As I don't have access to your date, be sure to have the correct layer names and try replacing `"osm_id"` with `$id` (no single or double quotes!).

Comment: How can I thank you? This is genius. It works. Probably it was just the wrong field type. It was quiet late... And now I know, that also the expression --> distance( 
 $geometry ,
  closest_point( 
   geometry(  get_feature_by_id ('bayern_25832gis_osm_waterways_free_1',
 array_to_string( overlay_nearest ( 'bayern_25832gis_osm_waterways_free_1', "osm_id" ) 
  )
   )
   ),
    $geometry ) ) worked. I extracted the values of both results (distance- expression and length(make_line-expression))  into .csv and the difference between them is always 0, for all 22.000 features.

Answer (score 0):

The way @babel and @biologist showed did not work.
Using `get_feature` instead of `get_feature_by_id` and aligning the reference field with the field referenced by `overlay_nearest` worked.

In @biologist's method, `overlay_nearest` returns the value of the "osm_id" field, which is probably a different value than the "id" that `get_feature_by_id` takes as an argument.
babel's method uses "$id" as the expression for `overlay_nearest`, but does this not return the geometry ID of the reference geometry, rather than the geometry ID of the search target?

like this:

```
distance( $geometry,
    closest_point(
        geometry(
            get_feature('line_layer','osm_id',
                array_to_string( 
                    overlay_nearest( 'line_layer',  "osm_id"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    , $geometry)
)
```