# Shortest distance between points and line

Tags: qgis-3

I am looking for the shortest distance between "n" points and lines.
I've been searching (I'm new to Qgis) and I get the expression:

```
length( make_line ( $geometry, closest_point ( geometry ( get_feature_by_id ( 'Shape_1', array_to_string ( overlay_nearest ( 'ADAMO_11', $id ) ) ) ) , $geometry ) ) )
```

With the "geometry Generator" it only makes lines at the symbology level but I cannot process the data.

I have extracted the information from: [QGIS 3.16.11 shortest distance between point and line via field calculator and overlay_nearest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412546/qgis-3-16-11-shortest-distance-between-point-and-line-via-field-calculator-and-o)

I add two screenshots, in the second the value that appears is not in meters. (I checked it with the ruler)

[image]

[image]

The expression that you indicate in the comment returns values ​​but they are not in meters.
I put it in the screenshot of the question.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Your question is not clear: where do you want to have the information? On the point or on the line layer? You want to add a value for the length to the attribute table or you want to draw the lines?

Comment: I need to know the distance from the points to the lines. I need the information on point.

Comment: There is a screenshot that I can't see in the comments of the post and it is where the problem was fixed @babel

Comment: The expression I use is:
length (
    make_line( 
    $geometry ,
        closest_point( 
            geometry(   
   get_feature_by_id (
   'ADAMO_11',
            array_to_string( 
   overlay_nearest ( 
   'ADAMO_11', 
   $id 
   ) 
          )
  )
      ),
    $geometry 
 ) 
  )
)

But the preview is "null"

Comment: There is no screenshot anywhere in the comments. It would be good if **you** could post a screenshot where we see what you do: how are the **names of your layers**, **where** do you want to apply the expression, what should the **result look like** etc. Simply providing an expression does not help much. Please edit your initial question and post any addition there, not in the comments.

Comment: Try this: `length ( make_line( $geometry , closest_point( overlay_nearest ( 'ADAMO_11', $geometry )[0] , $geometry ) ))`

Comment: I have already modified the question with screenshots

Answer (score 1):

If you run [`join attributes by nearest`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=join%20attributes%20nearest#join-attributes-by-nearest) with your pointlayer as first input and you line layer as second input, it will by default attach the attributes of the nearest line feature, as well as the distance to that feature, to your points.