# Finding nearest line feature from linear layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, features, proximity

I have two linear layers like you see below:

[image]

I would like to select just the nearest black lines to the red ones, which represent the other layer.

I found similar solutions, but they refer to the point layer instead:

[Find nearest line feature from point in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381056/find-nearest-line-feature-from-point-in-qgis)

Is there some way of making a selection of just these lines, which lie in the direct vicinity of the red line (another layer)?

**UPDATE I:**

The answer below brought me to the following approach:

[image]

[image]

the formula works, but I guess something is wrong with the Join by nearest option. I've set a unique id for both layers, one of them had already fid as the unique one. When the formula is applied, some parts of the layer are selected regardless of their vicinity to the other layer.

How should I do the Join by nearest option with respect to this situation?

Comment: Yes, indeed I just need the road lines, the very first lines which are visible next to the red line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you made clear in your comment, you're using QGIS 3.12, so you can't use the very handy [`overlay_nearest()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest) function, [introduced in QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core). So for older versions (tested with QGIS 3.12), you have to use a more complicated approach (that sayed: I heavily recommend updating to the current version!). Use this expression, replacing `line2` with the name of your line layer from where you want to find the closest line feature:

```
array_filter (
     array_foreach(
        aggregate ('line2', 'array_agg', $geometry),
        if (
            intersects(
                buffer (@element, 0.1), 
                closest_point (
                    aggregate ('line2', 'collect', $geometry),
                    $geometry
                )
            ),
            @element,
            NULL
        )
    ),
    @element is not NULL
) [0]
```

*Screenshot from QGIS 3.12: red line=layer `line1`, black lines= layer `line2`; yellow highlighted line is created with the expression from above, applied on `line1` (red line) to find the closest one of the black lines:*

[image]

---

If you need a selection on the layer with the black lines, use the expression from above with `Geometry by expression` to create the line as a separate layer. Than go the the initial black line layer, use Select by expression with this expression, where `Modified` the the name of the layer created with Geometry by expression:

```
intersects ($geometry, aggregate ('Modified', 'collect', $geometry))
```

Comment: Ok, will it work also as Select by expression? Instead of styling layer

Comment: Sorry, that is a complete different case. For select by expression, you must work on the layer you make the selection, thus on the black layer. If you work on the red layer, you can relatively easy find the the closest black line. It's more diffiult to work on the black layer to find... what? First the nearest red line, then from there go back to find the nearest black line... and repeat this for each feature of the black line. Seems too cumbersome to try. Why don't you want to update your installation? Much less headache, probably.

Comment: See updated answer how to make the selection.

Comment: I have no admin rights for the upgrade, that's he case. Tried your solution, but QGIS goes frozen, probably due to the size of my layer.

Comment: I see. Maybe breaking the size of the layer into smaller pieces could help. Large layer size is indeed tricky to overcome.

Comment: It doesn't work as my QGIS is constantly thrown away, but I will accept your answer as I believe it works correctly in normal conditions.

Answer (score 5):

You need a unique id field in your black line layer, mine is called id.

Join (by nearest) this id to the centerline so each centerline get the attribute of the closest black line. First split the centerline into short segments to be sure each nearest black line is found.

In the output you will have only the black ids closest to the centerline, the ids you want to select.

My output layer is called 'joined'. Select by expression on your black line layer with the expression:

```
array_contains(array:=
aggregate(layer:='joined', aggregate:='array_agg', expression:="id"), value:="id")
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, as all lines are being selected. I provided a unique ID both for the main layer as well as the other, but I am not sure how to execute the Join by nearest option.

Answer (score 3):

Use QGIS expressions with function [`overlay_nerarest()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest), [available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core), to identify the nearest line from another layer (here called `layer_2`). On the first layer (with the red line in your screenshot), run Geometry by expression with the following expression to create a layer containing the closest line:

```
overlay_nearest('layer_2', $geometry)[0]
```

---

Like this, you already have a layer with the lines you want. If you indeed want to have a selection on your initial `layer_2`, proceed as follows: On layer `layer_2` use `Select by Expression` with this expression:

```
overlay_within('Modified geometry')
```

Comment: I used to select by expression, but it looks like your formula is not known. Is it a correct or incorrect way I did it?

Comment: What QGIS version do you use?

Comment: I can't see what you did, so difficicult to say what went wrong. Please add details (e.g. what steps you did, exact error message etc) and a screenshot, if possible, to see what doesn't work

Comment: I use QGIS 3.12

Comment: OK, that explains why the expression doesn't work: overlay_ functions were introduced in QGIS 3.16 (see link in updated answer). You should update to a newer version. If you use an older version, this should be stated in the question, normally we assume you use the current version if not otherwise stated. With QGIS 3.12, you could use refFunctions plugin to achieve the same: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/

Comment: I've installed the plugin, but the plugin seems to not work. Formula either.

Comment: Not sure about the plugin, it seems to be outdated. I would heavily recommend installing the newest QGIS version instead as your installation is not supported any more.

Comment: Is there any solution for older QGIS version?